# How do I dynamically write a PHP object property name and set value?

Tags: php, php-8.1

I am using this to set the value.

```
$gallery = setDateFrom('2023-01-01');
```

But fields are coming in an array `['dateFrom', 'dateTo']`

```
$classKey = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
$gallery->{$classKey};
```

I am not able to add date to this property.

I tried `$classKey = 'set' . ucfirst($key) . "('$item')";`

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for calling by dynamic function Name. https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array

```php
<?php
function setDateFrom($val) {
    return 'it works ' . $val;
}

$arr = ['dateFrom', 'dateTo'];

$fnName = "set" . ucfirst($arr[0]);
echo call_user_func_array($fnName, ['test']);

// output: it works test
```